# How do I analyze Mergesort that uses Insertion Sort for small inputs?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, sorting

I know that Insertion Sort is faster when size $N$ is a small number, hence by modifying Merge Sort to use Insertion Sort when size $N$ reaches $K$, can help improve the performance.

How do I analyze this and prove that the running time of Merge Sort, $O(N \log N)$ is turned into $O(NK + N\log N(\frac{N}{K}))$?

I would really like to understand the analysis of this.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  What running time do you think that such an algorithm will have, and why?  We expect you to make a serious effort before asking here, and to show us what you tried and where you got stuck.  What makes you think that's the running time when using insertion sort like this?  What's the context where you ran into this?  We want to help you understand, not do exercises for you.

Comment: Have you checked out the (average-case) analysis of a similarly modified Quicksort, which is somewhat standard? Have you set up the recurrence and tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: You are using the _Big-O_ notation rendering constant factors irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It probably should be $O(NK + N \log \frac{N}{K})$.

Please try to figure out what do $NK$ and $N \log \frac{N}{K}$ represent.

Answer with details left blank:

> Consider the recursion tree. It has $\sim \frac{N}{K}$ leaves, and its height is $\sim \log \frac{N}{K}$.
>  At the leaves level, insertion sorts cost $\Box \cdot \Box = NK$ in total.
>  Then $\Box$ (how many?) merge stages follow, each of which costs $\Box$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just like Merge Sort upto Lg (n) levels but here we are merging only upto Lg (n/k) levels.At the last level there are n/k sub-lists each sub-list having k elements assuming uniform distribution (though same argument works for even if there's some sub-lists with less than k elements) although when they all have k elements it will be kind of the worst case since we have to sort maximum number of keys for each sub-list.
Each sub-list when sorted by Insertion-sort take theta(k^2) complexity and since there are n/k such sub-lists therefore total = (k^2)*(n/k) = n*k.

and now merging involves comparison at each level in the worst case we'll have to make at-most n comparisons at each level and total no of level can be calculated mathematically which comes out to be around Lg(n/k) or Lg(n/k)+1 which is almost same.
Total cost of merging is n*Lg(n/k) complexity.

Hence the total complexity of n*k + n*Lg(n/k).